# Get last record based on today's date

Tags: mysql

Hello I have a table for football games, and I need to get last game and next game based on today's date.

I have tried to use this query

```
SELECT DATE( match_date ) AS yesterday
FROM matches
WHERE DATE( match_date ) = DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 0 DAY ) ) 
GROUP BY yesterday
```

but the record can be before 2 days or 3 etc...

Also, for the `Next Game` If I use tomorrow date, I will not be sure if the game is exist on the next day or after.

I used this query to get all the games before today's date.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM matches
 WHERE DATE( match_date ) < DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 0 DAY ) )
```

What I need is if Today is `12-26-2012`, and the table like this

```
----------------------------------------------
    id         Date         Home        Away
----------------------------------------------
    1       2012-12-26       23          85
    2       2012-12-25       11          23
    3       2012-12-01       23          43
    4       2012-12-29       14          23
    5       2013-01-14       23          192
    6       2013-01-17       23          77


INPUT:  GET THE NEXT GAME FOR TEAM = 23 
OUTPUT: 4

INPUT: GET THE LAST GAME FOR TEAM = 23 
OUTPUT: 3
```

Comment: What is `id` in this table? The Team's id? Also m not clear as to what your output for the demo table signifies......

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher Match OR GAME ID, and it contains the results and everything in another table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last game:

```
SELECT DATE( match_date ) AS last_game
FROM matches
WHERE DATE( match_date ) < CURDATE()
ORDER BY match_date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

To get the next game:

```
SELECT DATE( match_date ) AS last_game
FROM matches
WHERE DATE( match_date ) > CURDATE()
ORDER BY match_date ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: How I can use this to filter the team home or away

Comment: The 2nd Query will not get the next game for the team, rather it'll fetch the id of the last game that will be played by the team, i.e. **OUTPUT: 6**

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher Why do you think so? Note that the order is ascending.

Comment: @SalmanA Thanks, edited. I assumed from the question that the OP wants to skip any games played today so you can't compare bare timestamps.

Comment: @Othman Just add `AND Home = 23` or whatever to the WHERE line.

Comment: @Juhana `AND HOME = 23 OR AWAY = 23` WILL FETCH 0 RECORDS

Comment: You need `AND ( home = 23 OR away = 23 )`. Do you get an error message from the query?

Comment: @Juhana: Sorry for jumping to that conclusion. The answer is correct. +1 for it!